# Creating a new form on click of link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How could I make it so the code below retains what it does now but does the following:

a) When the add menu link/button is clicked it shows the `bookingName` menu `div` and the same item and qty boxes

b) When the above happens it also needs the abilty to add more rows to that particular just added menu

[**Demo of current work**](http://jsfiddle.net/94ERj/)

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('<tr/>', {
        'class': 'menuDetails',
        html: getMenuHTMLDetails()
    }).appendTo('#addMoreItemsButton');
    $('#addItem').click(function () {
        $('<tr/>', {
            html: getMenuHTMLDetails()
        }).hide().appendTo('.menuDetailsBlock').slideDown('slow');
    });
})

function getMenuHTMLDetails() {
    var $clone = $('.menuDetails').clone();

    $clone.find('[name="item[]"]')[0].name = "item";
    $clone.find('[name="qty[]"]')[0].name = "qty";
    return $clone.html();
}
```

**HTML:**

```
      <div class="formBlock">
            <p><span class="bookingName">Menu<span class="required">*</span></span><span class="bookingInput"><input type="text" name="menu"/></span></p>
      </div>

<div class="formBlock">

<table class="menuDetailsBlock">
<tr>
<td><span class="bookingName">Item<span class="required">*</span></span></td>
<td><span class="bookingName">QTY<span class="required">*</span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="menuDetails">
<td><span class="bookingInput"><input type="text" name="item[]" /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="qty[]" style="width: 50px"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="bookingInput"><input type="text" name="item[]" /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="qty[]" style="width: 50px"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><span class="bookingInput"><input type="text" name="item[]" /></td>
<td><input type="number" name="qty[]" style="width: 50px"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>

    <div class="appendMoreItems"></div>
</div>
  <div class="formBlock">
              <a href="#" id="addItem">Add Item</a> <a href="" id="addMenu">Add Menu</a>
  </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should be aware of is that your html is invalid. You can't have something like:

```
<td><span>...</td><td>...</span></td>
```

Because this form needs the ability to be duplicated, you need to remove all IDs (and ideally change to them classes). e.g. `id="addMenu"` -> `class="addMenu"`.

Instead of using your standard click handler, you should use delegates to handle any clicks within your outer container - read http://api.jquery.com/on/.

As for your duplication problem, place a template of your elements to be duplicated inside a script tag with an id you can reference and clone (with `.html()`), or, even better, consider looking into http://handlebarsjs.com/ or http://akdubya.github.io/dustjs/.